# no directory when using /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p

Tags: unity, virtualbox, 20.04, 3d

I'm a beginner to Ubuntu.
I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 on VirtualBox. I need to know about the status of my  3D acceleration.
for this, I tried to use this command line:

/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p

but this message appears: " no such file or directory ".

Would you please help me step by step to resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you don't have unity installed.

You need to follow a different process to figure out if your VirtualBox 3D acceleration is working.

First install mesa-utils with `sudo apt install mesa-utils`.

Once the installation is done, run `glxinfo | grep 'renderer string'`.

That will return you the renderer string, which will tell you whether your virtual machine's OS is using VirtualBox's 3D acceleration.

Comment: Mine showed 'OpenGL renderer string: SVGA3D; build: RELEASE; LLVM;'

Comment: Christian, I just ran the command you suggested and realized you didn't really explain what "success" or "failure" looks like. I see that @Seunghoon reached out to you also for explanation. It would really help all, especially beginners to Ubuntu as the OP stated, if you would update your answer with what different results mean (like maybe a bullet list). I ran your suggested command, but as an Ubuntu newbie I don't know much about what it was supposed to do. Here is the result I received `llvmpipe (LLVM 12.0.0, 128 bits)` -- what does that even mean?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have `nux-tools` installed, or run this command and try again:

```
sudo apt install nux-tools
```